# How to apply dynamic Condition in scheduler in spring?

Tags: java, spring-boot, scheduled-tasks

I have an android app which reminds user to their specific Work at any Date and time that saved on database.

I want to create functionality that changes user work status after 30 min of their work time and for this I have to check in the Database every day and every second that Is there any work now?

I can use scheduler in spring boot, but how can I apply database stored time to run this schedule task?

There may possibly of no work then, there will be unnnecessary calls.

How can I apply condition that Scheduler must be call only when Work is ready?

Comment: maybe quartz scheduler is something you could use? http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/

Comment: no, multiple scheduling is not a problem. The problem is how we call schedule annotated method at our specific time. Thank you for your response.